# Get an index when using for_each in terraform

Tags: terraform

So with the following local variable I am trying to make a data call that will eventually need a constructed name using the following.

```
locals {
    environments = {
        test-env = {
          configurations = [
            {
              account_id   = "123456789"
              account_name = "account-name-1"
              team         = "team-1"
              alias        = "us-east"
            },
            {
              account_id   = "123456789"
              account_name = "account-name-1"
              team         = "team-1"
              alias        = "us-west"
            },
            {
              account_id   = "987654321"
              account_name = "account-name-2"
              team         = "team-1"
              alias        = "us-east-account-2"
            },
            {
              account_id   = "987654321"
              account_name = "account-name-2"
              team         = "team-1"
              alias        = "us-west-account"
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

So I first do the following:

```
locals {
    sdlc_config = flatten([
    for name, metadata in local.environments : [
      for config in metadata.configurations : {
        name         = name
        account_id   = config.account_id
        account_name = config.account_name
        team         = config.team
      }
    ]
])
```

That will get the configs to help construct the next map which is what is actually needed in the data call.

```
config_map = {
   for each in distinct(local. sdlc_config) : "${each.name}" => { config_name = "${each.account_name}-${each.team}-${each.account_id}" }...
}
```

The output for that will look like this:

```
{
   "test-env" = [
      {
         "config_name" = "account-name-1-team-1-123456789"
      },
      {
         "config_name" = "account-name-2-team-1-987654321"
      },
   ]
}
```

Now this is where I am having some issues, in the data call I try to use the config_name but since it is a map with a list of objects how can I get an index in the for_each function because an index is needed when iterating through.

```
data "configuration" "configurations" {
   for_each = local.config_map
   name     = each.value[index].config_name
}
```

How can I get an index within that for_each to iterate through the list of objects in the map?

Comment: Do you need the extra information, or could you simply transform the data structure into a `set` of the values e.g. `["account-name-1-team-1-123456789", "account-name-2-team-1-987654321"]`? That would be easy for you, and none of the other information is being used in your question.

Comment: Also, what are you hoping to iterate over for this final `configuration` data source? At the moment you will have one for each "env" (in this case you only have one: "test-env"); but are you actually wanting to have one for each account-team-accountid combination?

Comment: The data call will be used later when making a different resource call to get an id. In order to get each id I have to supply the key “test-env” which is why I was trying to iterate once already in the map.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this:

```
data "configuration" "configurations" {
   for_each = toset(local.environments.test-env.configurations)
   name     = "${each.value.account_name}-${each.value.team}-${each.value.account_id}"
}
```

Comment: But how would you do that when the key isn't known beforehand? It won't always be "test-env".

Comment: You never mentioned that in your question! But in that case you can first flatten local.environments.*.configurations and then do "for_each = toset(local.flattened_configs)"

Answer (score 0):

A key requirement of `for_each` is that you provide a mapping which has *one element per object you intend to declare*. Your current data structure doesn't seem to meet that requirement: instead, it has one element per environment, but each environment has multiple objects.

You will therefore need one more level of flattening, so that your `for_each` expression produces a single-level map of objects rather than a map of lists of objects.

For example:

```
locals {
  sdlc_config = flatten([
    for name, metadata in local.environments : [
      for config in metadata.configurations : {
        env_name     = name
        account_id   = config.account_id
        account_name = config.account_name
        team         = config.team
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "example" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for cfg in local.sdlc_config :
    "${cfg.env_name}-${cfg.account_name}-${cfg.team}-${cfg.account_id}" => cfg
  }

  name = each.key
  # ...
}
```

This will declare instances with unique addresses like this:

- `example.example["test-env-account-name-1-team-1-123456789"]`
- `example.example["test-env-account-name-2-team-1-987654321"]`

You can use expressions like `each.value.env_name`, `each.value.account_name`, etc to access the individual attributes corresponding with the compound key.